# Jenkins InfluxDB plugin connected to VictoriaMetrics

Tags: jenkins, influxdb

Does anyone know if there is possibility to send custom metrics to VictoriaMetrics server via InfluxDB plugin from Jenkins? In documentation it is mentioned that VictoriaMetrics supports Influx line protocol, but I cannot find information if these plugin uses it or puts data on the server in the other way.

If someone might had opportunity to connect these two, is it easy to fetch such a custom data from server to for example grafana?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'm not familiar with Jenkins, but if it should work. You can try to set VictoriaMetrics as a receiver for Jenkins and if it will not work - than create a [feature/bug request](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/issues/new/choose) at our [VictoriaMetrics Github page](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/). We also have a [guide "Migrate from InfluxDB to VictoriaMetrics"](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/guides/migrate-from-influx/) that cover the differences between two solutions, most commonly asked questions, and approaches for migrating from InfluxDB to VictoriaMetrics.